# The value doesn't change

Tags: roblox

I am making a sword fighting game where when you kill a player you get money. The money that you get is their level multiplied by 4. I made this script:

```
    local Players = game:GetService("Players")
    
    function PlayerAdded(player)
        local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
        leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
        local PStats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
        PStats.Name = "PlayerStats"
        
        local level = Instance.new("NumberValue", leaderstats)
        level.Name = "Level"
        level.Value = 1
        
        local reward = Instance.new("NumberValue", PStats)
        reward.Name = "Reward"
        reward.Value = level.Value * 4
    end
    Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(PlayerAdded)
```

and the value changer script

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local character = script.Parent
local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(character)
local humanoid = character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

local Level = player.leaderstats.Level
local Reward = player.PlayerStats.Reward

function UpdateReward()
    if player.leaderstats.Level.Changed then
        local newReward =  Level.Value * 4
        Reward.Value = newReward
        print("1")
    end
    wait(1)
    UpdateReward()
end
UpdateReward()
```

For some reason, the reward value isn't changing when the level does. I need help with this.

I was expecting the reward value to change

Answer (score 0):

You can’t get Value from a variable, so you would have to do leaderstats.Level.Value each time.

Comment: I remade the function, but it still doesn't work:
Reward.Value = Level.Value * 4
player.leaderstats.Level.Value.Changed:Connect(function()
 humanoid.Reward.Value = Level.Value * 4
 print(Reward.Value)
end)

Comment: @AlecSUS Is the value stored in the humanoid?

Comment: yes, it is stored there

Comment: @AlecSUS You should really store values in a folder in the player, otherwise all the values will be reset when they die…

Comment: i will try to...

Comment: i edited the post with the new script

Comment: @AlecSUS Is the second script local or server? If it’s server sided you need to loop through all players and make their reward update.